# Db2 : Is there any way to copy one database schema tables structure into another database schema..?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have one db2 database **testDb1** with *master* schema and second one is **testDb2** with *master* schema.

Now my question is how to copy master schema table structure of testDb1 to testDb2 master schema..?

Comment: Does your Db2-server run on Windows/Linux/Unix ?   IF so, you can use `db2look`.  **ALWAYS** specify your Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series , Linux/Unix/Windows)  when asking for help with Db2.

Comment: Db2-server run on windows and I am used DBeaver-6.2.1.

Comment: Much easier to achieve with a full Db2-client (installed on Windows) that includes the tool `db2look.exe`. Refer to the documentation (Db2 Knowledge Centre) for details of db2look and how to use it.  You can download a full Db2 client from IBM fix central or Passport Advantage.

Answer (score 2):

[db2look](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) is the answerto your queston as @mao mentioned already.

Run this on the source database

```
db2look -d testDb1 -e -z master -o db2look_testDb2_master.ddl
```

You will get a runnable script that could be aesily applied to the target database - just edit the script and change the name of the database in the connect statement.
Run the script with following command (from the command line)

```
db2 -tvf db2look_testDb2_master.ddl
```

Comment: how can I find generated ddl file. I mean where is the location of ddl file..?

Comment: Oh it is in the path you run that command from but you could also specify a full path for it in the command